# How can I receive push notifications from Amazon SNS using an event on CentOS, running Wildfly/JBoss?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jboss, centos, wildfly, amazon-mws

I intend to write software that posts daily feeds using [SubmitFeed](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/feeds/Feeds_SubmitFeed.html), and while planning to do so, I have seen in the documentation that I get some response from Amazon, possibly way before the actual parsing is complete. When I know that the operation has been completed, I need to call [GetFeedSubmissionResult](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/feeds/Feeds_GetFeedSubmissionResult.html), however, the problem is that I need to find out somehow when the submission has finished. I could poll using [GetFeedSubmissionList](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/feeds/Feeds_GetFeedSubmissionList.html) until the status is complete, but this would waste resources and is hacky. The way I would like to go is to use Amazon SNS and get notifications from [FeedProcessingFinishedNotification](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/notifications/Notifications_FeedProcessingFinishedNotification.html).

However, I don't know how I could use [Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc). Even though I read into the docs, I don't really know how I could use this. I suppose that something would need to run in my Linux CentOS or my Wildfly/Jboss which would "see" that a message has arrived and as a result would trigger the execution of a code I would intend to execute when such a push notification arrives. However, I do not know how I need to do this. How can I properly receive Amazon SNS push notifications at my Linux CentOS and Wildfly/Jboss so a custom Java code I write would be executed?

P.S.

This is a link which deals with RedHat and Maven: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/7.0-tp/html/apache_camel_component_reference/aws-sns-component

However, reading it it's not clear to me how I can receive messages from Amazon, like an order has been placed on a product.

This article about CLI: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-sns.html

describes how to subscribe using the email protocol. Reading about subscription protocols I have found this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html

It seems that if I choose an HTTPS address, then the messages would be requests to that address. I'm really confused about this.

Comment: It looks like you'll need to receive SQS messages, not SNS.  See [receiving notifications](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/subscriptions/Subscriptions_ReceivingNotifications.html) for details.  Did I miss something?

Comment: @stdunbar thanks for your comment. If I can set up to receive a FeedProcessingFinishedNotification when the feed posted by my SubmitFeed request is processed, then your suggestion is valid. I do not know whether that's the case with my limited AWS knowledge. Is that the case? According to what I was reading about this, I can set up some SNS feeds with aws cli and I was hoping that setting up a topic which equals to FeedProcessingFinishedNotification I would get push notifications from there. However, I just don't have enough information about AWS

Comment: Reading its docs is difficult to comprehend without practical examples to see and I do not dare to start setting up these things and potentially ruin the settings of the client before I have some minimal understanding about how to set up these push notifications.